# Find delimiter from textarea

Tags: javascript

The code below converts values separated by comma into array. Is it possible to find delimiter automatically - for example if user enters space or next line as delimiter between 2 numbers instead of comma?

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('df').value.split(',').map(Number))
```

```html
<textarea id='df' rows="5" cols="40">201,202,203</textarea>
```

Comment: You could use regular expressions to find all the numbers in the text and even check if there are letters to invalidate the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a Regex, as @kellys suggested to you in the comments. I wrote one for you but depends on what you expect to receive in the text area:

````
console.log(document.getElementById('df').value.split(/[ \n,]+/).map(Number))
```
````